# Timeline — wrong triangle direction

Tags: bug, status-completed, timeline

Why are the triangles in the timeline reversed?

[image: Wrong triangles]
<sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://xb5.xanga.com/9bcf4475d2330267842012/w213653566.png))</sub>

The majority uses ► (or ◢) for contracted items, and ▼ for expanded items, for example,

1. [image: Correct example 1]
   <sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://xdc.xanga.com/b01f7a6a09133267842008/w213653562.png))</sub>
2. [image: Correct example 2]
   <sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://xd6.xanga.com/c85f606a29132267842009/w213653563.png))</sub>
3. [image: Correct example 3]
   <sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://x7d.xanga.com/a6bf5a71d2331267842010/w213653564.png))</sub>

Comment: (in your registry example, isn't ◢ the expanded version? that doesn't change you point, though...)

Comment: It's the old, old question of whether a toggle button should show the current state, or what will happen when you click on it. I'm not aware that anyone has come up with a definitive answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, but..

Timeline is a beta, unnannounced feature that isn't even visible through any part of the public user interface.

Just sayin'